Interactive window takes long time when i run a python a cell in vscode
editor codeinteractive window out put
I am new to Python and programming, today I encountered a problem when I tried to run a selected line of code from vs code editor using an interactive window put as the attached image depicts it takes a long time to execute the command. I wonder whether or not the interactive window is working with the input function.
i appreciate in advance for your response
thanks

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It may take a little more time to open the interactive window for the first time, as additional packages need to be installed in the environment. It's a bit similar to when you use jupyter, where you can also switch kernel versions by clicking on the top right corner.


I wonder whether or not the interactive window is working with the input function.

If the input function you are referring to is typing python code and running it, then that is fine.
If you are trying to receive input in the code output, it is not possible.
